# URL Rewriting for images and css

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wonder if anyone can help with the below and if it is even possible.

I have a server running apache and know a little about url re-writing and wondered if it is possible to use url rewriting for paths for images and css.

so my current file structure is this:

```
/index.php
/theme/css/default.css
/theme/images/image1.jpg
```

in index.php i have the css linked to

```
/theme/css/default.css
```

but what i would actually like to display is

```
/css/default.css
```

also images are the same where i include an image it is

```
<img src=/theme/imaages/image1.jpg>
```

is it possible through rewriting to have

```
<img src=/imaages/image1.jpg>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy this code to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^theme/([a-z]+)/([a-z\-_\.]+)$ /$1/$2 [QSA,L]
```

(Make sure mod_rewrite is enable)

All the `<img src="/images/image1.jpg">` will redirect to `<img src="/theme/images/image1.jpg">` as well all the CSS files.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)I think it needs to be the other way round? so that if i have src=/images/image1.jpg it actually points to /theme/images/image1.jpg?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated my code. Yes /theme/images/image1.jpg will load /images/image1.jpg.